# Why System::Call is returning "0" when running 32-bit installer in 32-bit machine but when running it in 64-bit machine returning blank in NSIS

Tags: nsis

I have created a 32 bit installer using NSIS and that should run in both 32-bit or 64-bit machines.

The below code is working fine in 32-bit machine where it is calling the DLL (Profile.dll) using System::Call and the corresponding function IsSplashScreenDisabled(). This function returns false and showing the Message Box. It is working as expected.

But the same installer when I run in 64-bit machine, System::Call is not returning "0" instead it is showing blank "". So I am not getting the message box.

And also If I change "$PROGRAMFILES32" to "$PROGRAMFILES64" then also it is showing blank "" and not showing the Message Box.

So Here I need your suggestions or thoughts for why the System::Call is working differently with 32-bit/64-bit installer and in 32-bit or 64-bit machines.

```
!include LogicLib.nsh

InstallDir $PROGRAMFILES32\MyAppTest

Page components
Page directory
Page instfiles

UninstPage uninstConfirm
UninstPage instfiles

Section
SetOutPath $INSTDIR
  File E:\TestNullSoft\Test.dll

System::Call 'KERNEL32::AddDllDirectory(w "$INSTDIR")'

 System::Call "$INSTDIR\Test.dll::IsSplashDisabled() i.r0 ?e" 
  Pop $1 
  ${If} $0 = 0
    
    MessageBox MB_OK|MB_ICONEXCLAMATION "Splash s Disabled.$\r$\nRolling back the installation..." IDOK

  ${EndIf}
SectionEnd


BOOL IsSplashDisabled()
{
    BOOL    bResult = FALSE;
    DWORD   dwSplashScreen(0);
    RegistryObj regObj(SETTINGS_REG_PATH);
    
    if (regObj.Get(SPLASH_SCREEN, testSplashScreen))
    {
        bResult = (BOOL) !testSplashScreen;
    }

    return  bResult;
}
```

Comment: Can you post some more information about Profile.dll. Did you write IsSplashScreenDisabled?

Comment: In the Profile.dll I have written the function IsSplashScreenDisalbled. This function is returning false as I haven't  registered it in the registry. I have written this function in the above post. Please have a look.

Comment: Is it stdcall or cdecl? Not that it matters much when there are no parameters but unless you are able to upload a sample .dll somewhere I'll probably have to try to make my own.

Comment: Hi @Anders, it is cdecl function.

Comment: And also I am exporting this function using __declspec(dllexport). Even If i give Profile.dll, it won't work because there are many dependent dlls required along with this DLL.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide a sample .dll, at this point I can't tell if dependent .dlls are the problem or not.

Comment: Hi @Anders, How can i share the sample dll to you?

Comment: Both Google Drive and OneDrive allows you to share files. Or use a file sharing service like Mega etc. Or create an account on the NSIS/WinAmp forum and attach the file there.

Comment: There is no Profile.dll in there. Upload a simple .dll that just does a MessageBox and include the source, otherwise I can't help you. You did not write drvutil, ask the author for help with those.

Comment: Without $InstsDir will only work because of AddDllDirectory. What is the value of $InstDir when it fails? It might be a problem with the "(x86)" part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way `System::Call` parses the string has a flaw, if the string contains `(..)` it will parse that as the function parameters and it fails to load the .DLL and the call fails. On 64-bit Windows $ProgramFiles32 contains `(x86)` as part of the path and this triggers the flaw.

There are two ways to work around this:

**A)**

Use a combination of `SetOutPath` and `AddDllDirectory` to make sure the .DLL can be loaded from a relative path:

```
SetOutPath $InstDir
System::Call 'KERNEL32::AddDllDirectory(w "$INSTDIR")'
File MyFile.dll

System::Call 'MyFile::MyFunction()i.r0'
```

`SetOutPath` makes the path the current directory and `AddDllDirectory` adds the directory to the list of valid directories to load from.

**B)**

Manually load the .DLL and call the address directly:

```
SetOutPath $InstDir
System::Call 'KERNEL32::AddDllDirectory(w "$INSTDIR")'
File MyFile.dll

System::Call 'KERNEL32::LoadLibrary(t "$InstDir\MyFile.dll")p.r1'
${If} $1 P<> 0
    System::Call 'KERNEL32::GetProcAddress(pr1,m "MyFunction")p.r2'
    ${If} $2 P<> 0
        System::Call '::$2()i.r0'
    ${EndIf}
    System::Call 'KERNEL32::FreeLibrary(pr1)'
${EndIf}
```

Comment: There is already a NSIS bug report for this, I'll see what I can do to get it fixed.